# How can I check a docker image if theres are commands run by root

Tags: docker, openshift

I'm running openshift and it does not allow docker containers to run commands as root.

Is there a easy way to check if a custom docker image has commands run by root?

Comment: Try and run it locally using ``docker run -u 11111111 imagename``. The ``-u`` with large number simulates what will happen with OpenShift whereby forced to run as specific UID. If it fails, you know it likely isn't going to work. This will catch problems where image expects to run as set non root user ID as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is correct, docker doesn't care what's going on within a VM, and root command would only be able to damage it's own VM.

That said you can open a shell on the image and do some checks

```
docker run -it gregclinker/boot-docker:1.0.3 /bin/sh
```

Then you could do:

```
ps -ef
```

to check any background processes running and so on.